# Canon Pixma iP2820 Driver for Ubuntu?

Tags: printing, canon

There is no official driver. (I know that. I've spent 5 hours looking)
But is there another way to get it to work? I plugged it in, and the driver didn't automatically install, so I searched Google. (5 hours looking, still.) No Drivers.
I also have Wine (Windows Compatibility Layer & Program Loader) but the Windows Driver Setup (official version) did not work either.

I am using a USB cable to connect to the printer, and the printer is on and fully set up.

And, In "How can I install a Canon printer or scanner driver?" there still is no iP2820.
So, I would not consider it a duplicate. The answers there do not answer this question!

Answer (score 0):

In case you are still wondering. Download this driver for linux:

http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0100586502.html

Unzip and execute the install.sh script:

./install.sh

Comment: I'll just keep this question here so other people can find this answer.